# Differentiable curves that are not smooth

Tags: geometry, intuition, curves

We call a curve admitting a parameterization $t\to z(t)$, $t\in[0,1]$ differentiable if the vector function $z$ is differentiable. We call the curve smooth if it is differentiable and its derivative is non-zero.

What are examples of differentiable curves that are not smooth? What are the geometrical differences between the two types? Are there curves, which are not smooth at a point and still have a unique tangent at that point? Which are some differentiable curves do not have a tangent.

Comment: For example, $t \mapsto (t^3,t^9)$.

Comment: Your definition seems a bit hazy. You say 'a curve admitting a parametrization $z$', which suggests that your curve is defined only by its points (and not by the specific parametrization). But your definition of 'differentiable' depends on the parametrization. So what does 'curve' mean to you? A set of points which admits a continuous parametrization, or the specific parametrization itself?

Comment: Differentiability of a parameterization is invariant under admissible changes of the parameter. An admissible change of the parameter, in the case of differentiable curves, is synonymous with a differentiable change. Therefore, my definition of differentiable does not depend on the parameterization. From a logical point of view, it is most convenient call the parameterization function the curve. However, the image of the curve is invariant under continuous re-parameterizations. A curve to me is the set of points, since all the properties are re-parameterization invariant.

Comment: @Student: Take Seirios' example $z(t)=(t^3,t^9)$. The derivative of $z$ vanishes at $(0,0)$. But the same curve is also parameterized by $z(t)=(t,t^3)$, whose derivative $(1,3t^2)$ vanishes nowhere. So your definiton of 'smooth' is flawed, because it depends on the parametrization.

Answer (score -2):

the smoothness that you mean is what we call geometric continuity of a curve , in other words a curve is sad to be geometric continuous if it has at each point a tangent vector and varie continuously along the curve.
I m interseting at such field of geometry,  i will be happy if you give me any open question in .